# Why am i being asked for password in site for default.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Why when I have forms authentication selected as below in my web config does it go to login.aspx for the request of file default.aspx which is in the root not the ~/account folder any suggestions for what i need to check thanks

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"></forms>
</authentication>


<location path="~/WebResource.axd">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="~/Account">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="img">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="~/ScriptResource.axd">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="~/contactus.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: You don't have any authorization rules outside the <location> tags? If no then the default rule should work which allows anonymous users to access all pages. If not you may consider to create a web.config file for Account folder and remove all the relevant rules from the website web.config

Answer (score 1):

To allow anonymous users access Default.aspx is root you should try:

```
<location path="~/Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a rule to explicitly let people view contactus.aspx, but no matching rule for default.aspx.  Try adding a rule for that area.

I'm assuming you have a deny all rule somewhere that you haven't shown?  You could always grant access to all of your site and then explicitly deny access to just /account as you have done.

Answer (score 0):

What is in your authentication section of the web.config?

Its' been a while but I think you have to explicitly grant access to things I think by default it is classed as locked down?

So you will need a root level grant permission.

Answer (score 0):

Add following block in web.config if you wish all users to visit the page without login

```
<location path="~/Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

it sets to allow anonymous users to this page